# QStyledItemDelegate: how to make checkbox button to change its state on click

Tags: qt, qcheckbox, qstyleditemdelegate

I have a delegate `MyDelegate` which is used for `QListWidget`. The delegate is derived from `QStyledItemDelegate`. One of the goals of `MyDelegate` is to place a checkbox button on each row of `ListWidget`. It is done within the `paint()` event of `MyDelegate`:

```
void MyDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    // ... drawing other delegate elements

    QStyleOptionButton checkbox;
    // setting up checkbox's size and position

    // now draw the checkbox
    QApplication::style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_CheckBox, &checkbox, painter);
}
```

At first I thought the checkbox would automatically change its state on click, since I specified `QStyle::CE_CheckBox`. But it is not the case. Looks like I have to specify the checkbox visual behavior manually.

Data-wise, When user clicks on that checkbox, certain signal is emitted and the scene data is changed. I perform this action in `editorEvent()`:

```
bool MyDelegate::editorEvent(QEvent *event, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index)  
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease) {
        if (/* within checkbox area */)
            emit this->clickedCheckbox(index);
    }
}
```

The backend part works. However, I cannot figure out how to make the checkbox button to change its visual state from checked to unchecked, and backwards.

I realized that I can change the checkbox state manually by doing something like this from `paint()`:

```
checkbox.state = someCondition? (QStyle::State_Enabled | QStyle::State_On) :
                           (QStyle::State_Enabled | QStyle::State_Off) ;
```

`QStyle::State_On/Off` does the trick of manual checkbox state change.

But I do not know how to set up that `someCondition` and where I should set it up. I tried to introduce it as a private `bool` variable which would be set in `editorEvent()` when the checkbox area gets a click, however, it does not produce the desired behavior: it sets all the other checkboxes of `ListWidget` to the same visual state. So, it behaved like some global condition for all the checkboxes.

I feel like, to accomplish my task, I have to re-implement the button and make it to change the checkbox state on click. But I'm lost on this way and not sure how to approach the problem. From the [`QStyleOptionButton` API](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstyleoptionbutton-members.html) I do not see a `clicked()` or any other method I could use.

So, the question is: how do I make checkbox to behave like a checkbox, visually? If I need to re-implement a checkbox, then what class do I inherit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set some value that describes your checkbox state in `MyDelegate::editorEvent` and then use it to paint a proper checkbox:

```
const int CHECK_ROLE = Qt::UserRole + 1;

bool MyDelegate::editorEvent(QEvent *event,
                            QAbstractItemModel *model,
                            const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                            const QModelIndex &index)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
    {
        bool value = index.data(CHECK_ROLE).toBool();

        // invert checkbox state
        model->setData(index, !value, CHECK_ROLE);

        return true;
    }

    return QStyledItemDelegate::editorEvent(event, model, option, index);
}

void MyDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, 
                      const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, 
                      const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QStyleOptionButton cbOpt;
    cbOpt.rect = option.rect;

    bool isChecked = index.data(CHECK_ROLE).toBool();
    if (isChecked)
    {
        cbOpt.state |= QStyle::State_On;
    }
    else
    {
        cbOpt.state |= QStyle::State_Off;
    }

    QApplication::style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_CheckBox, &cbOpt, painter);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, it works. For clarification: how did you come up with the `CHECK_ROLE` variable and why do you assign it to exactly `Qt::UserRole + 1`. Is that some common practice?

Comment: `QAbstractItemModel` derived models can store data of different roles. Some of these roles are predefined, like `Qt::DisplayRole`. `Qt::UserRole` is the first role which you can use for your special purposes. So, actually `CHECK_ROLE` could be equal to that value. See http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum

Answer (score 5):

I added the following:

- data(Qt:CheckStateRole) is toggled.
- enable/disable the item.
- center the box in the cell.
- only toggle checkmark with left mouse button, and when checkmark is clicked (not the entire cell).

Here's the code:

```
// -------------------------------- //
class GFQtCheckboxItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    const int CHECK_ROLE = Qt::CheckStateRole;

    // dont't let the default QStyledItemDelegate create the true/false combobox
    QWidget* createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        (void)parent;
        (void)option;
        (void)index;
        return nullptr;
    }


    QRect GetCheckboxRect(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option)const
    {
        QStyleOptionButton opt_button;
        opt_button.QStyleOption::operator=(option);
        QRect sz = QApplication::style()->subElementRect(QStyle::SE_ViewItemCheckIndicator, &opt_button);
        QRect r = option.rect;
        // center 'sz' within 'r'
        int dx = (r.width() - sz.width())/2;
        int dy = (r.height()- sz.height())/2;
        r.setTopLeft(r.topLeft() + QPoint(dx,dy));
        r.setWidth(sz.width());
        r.setHeight(sz.height());

        return r;
    }


    // click event
    bool editorEvent(QEvent *event, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index)
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
        {
            QMouseEvent* pME = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
            if(pME->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
            {
                QRect ro = GetCheckboxRect(option);
                QPoint pte = pME->pos();
                if(ro.contains(pte) )
                {
                    bool value = index.data( CHECK_ROLE).toBool();

                    // invert checkbox state
                    model->setData(index, !value, CHECK_ROLE);

                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return QStyledItemDelegate::editorEvent(event, model, option, index);
    }

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
    {
        QStyleOptionButton cbOpt;
        cbOpt.rect = GetCheckboxRect(option);

        bool isChecked = index.data(CHECK_ROLE ).toBool();
        if (isChecked)
        {
            cbOpt.state |= QStyle::State_On;
        }
        else
        {
            cbOpt.state |= QStyle::State_Off;
        }

        QVariant enabled = index.data(Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
        if(enabled.isNull() || enabled.toBool() )
        {
            cbOpt.state |= QStyle::State_Enabled;
        }

        QApplication::style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_CheckBox, &cbOpt, painter);
    }
};
```

And for completeness, here's how to apply it:

```
m_p_QTableView->setItemDelegateForColumn(iTableColumnIndex, new GFQtCheckboxItemDelegate() );
...
bool yesno ...;
pGrid->setData(index, yesno, Qt::CheckStateRole);
```

[qt](/questions/tagged/qt)[qcheckbox](/questions/tagged/qcheckbox)[qtableview](/questions/tagged/qtableview)

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier if you change the QListWidget to a QListModel and a QListView.

```
Qt::ItemFlags ListModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    return QAbstractListModel::flags(index) | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable;
}

QVariant ListModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (role == Qt::EditRole) {
        return m_checkStateForRow[index.row()];
    }
}

bool ListModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    if (role == Qt::CheckStateRole) {
        m_checkStateForRow[index.row()] = value.toInt();
        emit dataChanged(index, index, {role});
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```